# Drupal-6 multiple profiles selections after installation?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules, profile

I have created multiple profiles in my Drupal site. Currently Drupal allows us to select any 1 profile during installation.

But I need to change it a bit, what I want is that the admin can choose any profile after the drupal installation finished.

Is there any way to get around with this problem. I have googled for almost an hour now, but no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're talking about installation profiles? The answer is a resounding no I'm afraid, they are *installation* profiles, they don't do anything after the installation has taken place so allowing an admin to 'choose' a profile on a fully installed site would have absolutely zero effect.

If you really want to do it though (as an exercise into getting to know Drupal or something) then run this PHP code:

```
variable_set('install_profile', 'name_of_profile');
```

As I say though, I can see zero value to calling that as it will make no difference whatsoever to your site once it's been installed.